# Multiple inheritance: diamond shape, constructor in derived sub class

Tags: c++

I have the following class structure:

```
  A
 / \* both virtual
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

Each class needs a constructor with 3 parameters, they look like this:

```
A::A(int a, int b, int c) 
{
  //use a,b,c
  //some memory allocation
}

B::B(int a, int b, int c) :
    A(a,b,c)
{
  //some memory allocation
}

C::C(int a, int b, int c) :
    A(a,b,c)
{
  //some memory allocation
}
```

So I just pass the initialization values to A, because A is the only one which handles them.

So, no I ran into problems when trying to write the constructor for D.
I have the following:

```
D::D(int a, int b, int c) :
   A(a,b,c),
   B(a,b,c),
   C(a,b,c) // ERROR AT THIS LINE
{
   // some memory allocation
}
```

since B and C virtual inherit from A, diamond shape problem should be solved, right?
However I am getting several error messages like

```
undefined reference to 'VTT for D'
```

Did I do something very basically wrong? I can post more code, like full class structure if needed, or if my mistake does not show in these code snippets.

Comment: The error message appears to be a link time error. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why would you call constructor of A from constructor of D? It is already called by B and C.

Comment: Try this:  `class A {
protected:
    A(int a, int b, int c){}
    A() { throw std::runtime_error("should never be called"); }
};

class B : public virtual A {

};

class C : public virtual A {

};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D(int a, int b, int c) : A(a, b, c) {}
}; `

Comment: @rhobincu: Since `A` is a virtual base class, its constructor is called directly from the constructor of `D`.

Comment: @rhobincu, if you want to avoid calling the constructor, you need to declare a default constructor in A to enable the implicit default constructors of B and C. This constructor will never be called though, because D calls `A(int, int, int)`. (See the code in my previous comment)

Comment: This sort of link error is usually caused by forgetting to implement some virtual function declared in `D`.

Comment: @aschepler you are brilliant! That was exactly my mistake. I was so focused on getting the constructor right, that I missed implementing the virtual functions. And the error message inside the constructor made it worse :D thanks a lot